# ViewPager не отображается в scrollview

Tags: android-viewpager, android, android-scrollview

Здравствуйте.

Имею группу view, которые образуют собой фрагмент. В данной группе есть viewPager. FrameLayout, в который это фрагмент выводится, лежит в scrollview. Возникла проблема: почему-то именно viewPager в скролле не отображается. Все элементы группы есть, а его нет.
В чем может быть причина?

Активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/background_light">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/blue_light"     android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvNameTest" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" style="@style/child_text_form"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="none">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@color/blue_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/containerQuestion">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:id="@+id/ivLastQuestion" android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="0.1" android:padding="8dp"
                           android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTextQuestion" style="@style/main_text_form" android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/ivNextQuestion" android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="0.1" android:padding="8dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/frameFragment">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" android:src="@drawable/shadow"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Фрагмент:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/white">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/vPager"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lMark"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: проблема в вашем коде.

Comment: Вот бы узнать, где именно в коде ошибка. Добавил код активити и фрагмента. Если убрать scrollview, то тогда все хорошо отображается.

Comment: Мне помогло это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-viewpager-inside-of-a-scrollview?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Когда ViewPager находится в ScrollView, то он(ViewPager) должен иметь фиксированную высоту. Если потребуется динамически менять высоту, то следует это делать из java-кода.